# Yesod Persistence - Aggregate functions

Tags: database, haskell, yesod

I'm evaluating `Yesod` as a platform for writing a web-based accounting software for in-house use. So far I'm impressed.

Modelling the entities to suit Persistent is pretty straight-forward, being able to set column names helps greatly as the database with accounting entries already exists.

However I will need to eventually run queries that aggregate the data also, ie. give me the balance for this account. Can this be expressed within `Persistent`?

Comment: If @MichaelSnoyman doesn't appear and do his magic, you might be interested in [`esqueleto`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto), a library that is used on top of `persistent` to do more advanced queries.

Comment: that looks promising at first glance. Not sure yet if it will do sum() though. But quite useful to know even if it doesn't. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You just do `sum = unsafeSqlFunction "SUM"` and you suddenly have support for it (Albeit somewhat hacky)!

Comment: does this help? http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent-raw-sql-133

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with Haskell, but quite experienced with RDBMS. If you start doing anything even remotely interesting with the database then Persistent isn't going to be much use - you'll be writing plenty of raw SQL. Can't comment on esqueleto - only read one blog post about it.

Comment: Disappointed that this got asked more than 5 years ago and there still isn't a solution.